# Changed variables not affecting while loop

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

Recently I have been trying to write a program that would give questions to the user and then check the answers. But there is a problem:

```
get_questions=["What color is the daytime sky on a clear day? ", "blue",
               "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything? ", "42",
               "What is a three letter word for mouse trap? ", "cat",
               "What noise does a truly advanced machine make?","ping"]
total=0
total2=0
good=0
def give_questions():
    global get_questions
    global total2
    global total
    global good
    add1=0
    add2=1
    question=get_questions[add1]
    answer=get_questions[add2]
    print
    while total != 4:
        print question
        print
        answer_given=raw_input("Answer: ")
        if answer_given != answer:
                print
                print "Wrong. The correct answer was",answer,"."  
                print
                total2=total2+1
                total=total+1
                add1=add1+2
                add2=add2+2
        else:
                print
                print "Correct"
                print
                total2=total2+1
                total=total+1
                good=good+1
                add1=add1+2
                add2=add2+2
give_questions()
```

Whenever I run this, strangely the same question and answer run again and again until the variable `total` has reached 4. When I wrote `print add2` in the if statement, it went from 1 to 3 to 5, as expected. but the question or answer won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update your question and answer as they are outside your 'while' loop. Therefore all the way through your loop it will keep asking you the same question. Below is an example code with `question = get_questions[add1]` and `answer = get_questions[add2]` moved inside the `while` loop:

```
get_questions = ["What color is the daytime sky on a clear day? ", "blue",
                 "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything? ", "42",
                 "What is a three letter word for mouse trap? ", "cat",
                 "What noise does a truly advanced machine make?", "ping"]
total = 0
total2 = 0
good = 0

def give_questions():
    global get_questions
    global total
    global total2
    global good
    add1 = 0
    add2 = 1

    while total != 4:
        question = get_questions[add1]
        answer = get_questions[add2]

        print(question)
        answer_given = input("Answer:")
        if answer_given != answer:
            print ("Wrong. The correct answer was" ,answer)
            total2 += 1
            total += 1
            add1 += 2
            add2 += 2

        else:
            print ("Correct")
            total2 += 1
            total += 1
            good += 1
            add1 += 2
            add2 += 2

give_questions()
```

**Note:** There seems to be a lot of unnecessary 'print' statements in your code which don't appear to do anything. I have removed them from the above code in order to simplify it.

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer.